# What server specs would be needed to handle an ASP.NET website with the following usage?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, dedicated-server, hardware

I'm currently re-developing an ASP.NET website for a client and they want to upgrade their server hardware, but they're not sure to what.

The current server specs are: AMD Athlon 3200+ with 2GB RAM, running both IIS and SQL Server 2005.

The traffic for the existing site averages: 36,500 unique visitors and 220,000 page-views a month, and according to the client, the current server has difficulty handling the requests.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bigger server? Seriously, this is a "no idea" talk. I likely would go with a higher range server and virtualize it. YOU have to tell us where the problem is. "It is slow" is like "the food is not good". You have to give details. YOU are the person with access to the machine.

You memory is quite pathetic - so more memory it is, and likely you are limited on the rest too.

Get a 4-8 core cpu (amd or intel), decent ram and enough SSD to handle the IO and you should be set quite some time.

Btw., I also vote to close - shopping questions are off topic here.

Comment: I just needed an approximate idea, which you've given, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for a trial and install the [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) .net client on the current machine.

I recently took this step on a site where we had spent an awful lot of time addressing performance with caching. It turned out that we needed a set of indexes on the DB.

New Relic immediately identified the slow transaction *and* displayed the SQL queries that were responsible.

It displays a breakdown of what the server is spending time doing. So that you can target your improvements.

---

That said I agree that 2GB RAM with a web server that is running SQL and IIS is likely to be your problem.

Disclaimer: I have no connection with New Relic except using it happily myself.